# PHP Multidimensional Array Merge Issue

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I am running a query that outputs a multidimensional array like this: -

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 772
                [display_name] => Test Company Ltd
                [profile_page] => partners/test-company
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 772
                [display_name] => Test Company Ltd
                [profile_page] => partners/test-company

            )

)
```

I am trying to make the Array look like this so that we can loop through it on our site: -

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 772
        [display_name] => Test Company Ltd
        [profile_page] => partners/test-company
    )
)
```

This is all being generated using PHP using Symfony2 and Doctrine2. I have tried a couple of methods to get this working but I have reverted back to my first method which is this: -

```
$companies = array();

foreach($postcodes as $key=>$value) {
    $conn = $em->getConnection();

    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT a.id, a.display_name, a.profile_page, b.meta_data FROM companies a, `cms`.pages b WHERE b.slug = a.profile_page AND a.active = 1 AND a.postcode = ".$value."  ORDER BY a.display_name ASC");
    $execute = $query->execute();
    $companies[] = array_replace_recursive($query->fetchAll());
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($companies); echo '</pre>';

die();
```

If someone can show me how to get around this, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$query->fetchAll()` is itself is an multidimensional array you're in need.

Just replace following line

```
$companies[] = array_replace_recursive($query->fetchAll());
```

with

```
$innCompnies=$query->fetchAll();
foreach($innCompnies as $inComp) {
     $companies[]=$inComp;
}
```

It wasn't working because you were pushing multidimensional array into another array.  What we actually need to do is to push element one by one into the main array.

Comment: I tried this and when I remove the square brackets from $companies as well as the array_replace_recursive it showed an empty array. When I put the square brackets back in and removed the array_replace_recursive, I have exactly the same answer as before.

Comment: Hi Alok, thats great and that worked a treat. Thank you. However, how would I merge it as the two values are similar.

Comment: You will need to keep track of the IDs you visit in `foreach` only insert array if the id is not visited before.

Comment: Of course. Monday mornings eh? Thank you Alok. I will mark this as answered. Thanks again mate, I really appreciate your help. Sometimes too much coding can cloud your judgement, haha!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to avoid SQL-queries in loop. Also you have potential SQL-injection vulnerability concatenating postcodes to your query. So the possible solution may be replacing your foreach loop with something like:

```
$companies = $conn->fetchAll(
    "SELECT a.id, a.display_name, a.profile_page, b.meta_data FROM companies a, `cms`.pages b WHERE b.slug = a.profile_page AND a.active = 1 AND a.postcode IN :postcodes  ORDER BY a.display_name ASC",
    compact('postcodes')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can transform the multidimentional array like this.

```
$new_companies = array();
array_walk($companies, function($companie) use($companies, &$new_companies){
  if(is_array($companie)) {
    foreach ($companie as $c) {
        $new_companies[] = $c;
    }
  }
});
```

$new_companies is what you want.